# How to render mongodb data to ejs file?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am learning how to display mongodb data in html, but the code cannot work when I learn from network. I want to create the button to change the page to view data, and I don't know how to render data to ejs.

I try to find some method to solve the problem in network, but most of them are  not the problem which I get.
code of find data

```
app.post('/viewdata', function (req, res) {
res.render('staffDisplay');
try{
    MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, client) {
        if(err) {
             console.log('Error occurred while connecting to MongoDB Atlas...\n',err);
        }else{
           var game=[];
           var collection = client.db("GameDB").collection("Game");
           var result = collection.find();

           result.forEach(function(error,result){
               if(error){
                   console.log(error);
               }else{
                   if(result != null){
                       game.push(result);
                   }else{
                       console.log(game);
                       res.render('views/staffDisplay.ejs',{game:result})
                   }
               }
           })

           console.log('show');
            client.close();
        }
     });
}catch(ex){
    throw new Error(ex.toString());
}
});
```

display.ejs

```
//skip the html code

        <ul>
      <% for(var i=0;i<=game.length;i++) {%>
      <li><%=game[i].gName%></li>
      <li><%=game[i].gDesc%></li>
      <li><%=game[i].gDate%></li>
      <%}%>
    </ul>
```

the result is display 'game is not define', how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove this `res.render('staffDisplay');` on the first part then replace `res.render('views/staffDisplay.ejs',{game:result})` with this `res.render('staffDisplay.ejs',{game:result})`

Comment: it does not work, the result still is 'game is not defined'